# How to keep up-to-date offline artifactory repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, artifactory, offline-mode

I have artifactory running offline which is on seperate network and has no internet connection.
When I need an artifact for the project:

1. I update pom.xml of template eclipse project(internet network)
2. export artifactory (all repositories)(internet network)
3. import artifactory repositories(closed network)
4. add artifact to pom.xml to download artifactory(closed network)

I usually use dependency plugin with go-offline option that I can do on project level.  I can't download maven central repository though.

Problem is when I need a small single artifact I have to go through this cycle.
Is there an easy way to do this?

thanks